UPBGE Viewport not fully updating after shifting vertices
I'm messing with Blender UPBGE 0.2.5b. which is with Python 3.7.0.
I have a python script within game engine with which i'm able to move vertex points of subdivided planes or a cube and which i used to determine which vertex is which for geometry on layer two.
And unfortunately i have ran into a problem with it updating what i see, while even the reinstancePhysicsMesh is being ran simultaneously along with the vertex moving script.
I have enabled Physics visualization along with Show bounding box.
So imagine, i move 1st to 8th(last) vertex point to a cursor object. And in result, the red line box shifts away along with the green geometry lines and is no longer in cubes original location. And one side of pink bounding box stays in its original location while its other side drags or stretches along the green textured mesh and the red stretching box lines - and i guess it's because of the origin point which stays in place.
The problem is that after shifting away 1st to last vert, i saw stretching triangles with stretched textures stretching away while most of what was visible before i started shifting verts - remain visually in their starting position except the top and the bottom faces which seem to be invisible - what i inspected by adding control to camera for going around.
Any idea what am i doing wrong? As when i was shifting verts of subdivided planes to determine which vert is which, i didn't had sutch issue or a problem.

Even if i switch to from wireframe to material shading, these faces are still there.
Many thanks in advance.

Although there is still a game-engine tag you're unlikely to find any answers here as very few UPBGE users frequent this Q&A site nowadays. - UPBGE was split from basic Blender when the game engine was removed from Blender 2.83 in 2020. There have only been around 15 questions asked about it here this year most of those being unanswered. Issues with UPBGE can be submitted here.

Much thanks for Your reply, i'll give it a shot.
Will see if i'm any lucky with this one. Have a nice day.
